# Python: How to find matching data entries and perform efficient computation between two datasets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say, for example, that I have two datasets stored in the form of Pandas dataframes like this:

```
Data1:
   C1      C2
"Peter"  "kiwi"
"John"   "banana"
"Susan"  "peach"
"Joe"    "apple"

Data2:
   C3      C4
"apple"     4 
"banana"    7
"apple"     4
```

I would like to first cache the indices of matching data entries between two Pandas data frames. This part is not counted in my runtime analysis and would be good to compute up front for more efficient hash lookups later on.

e.g. desired output

```
 {banana: [1]      (banana from Data1 matches with row 1 in Data2)
 apple: [0,2]}     (apple from Data1 matches with row 0 & 2 in Data2)
```

Then, for each row in data1, I would like to sum the Data2[C4] values for all matches found.  More concretely to the example, I want the resulting computation to be like:

```
"Peter":  0 (no match for "kiwi")
"John":   7 (one match for "banana", it's just 7)
"Susan":  0 (no match for "peach")
"Joe":    8 (two matches for "apple", they're 4+4)
```

Is there a good way to accomplish this using the pandas dataframe, or numpy, efficiently? Aka use intermediate steps from computing the dictionary to help increase the speed of the summations later.

Note:

The first task can be done by something like

```
Data1.reset_index().groupby('C3')['index'].apply(list).loc[Data0.C2.unique()]
```

The second task can be done by something like

```
Data0['W'] = Data0['C2'].map(Data1.set_index('C3', append=True)) \
                        .sum(level=1)['C4']).fillna(0)
```

But not sure how to take advantage of the work used in the first part to help in computation with the second part.

Comment: do you need the intermediary dictionary (`{banana: [1], ...}`) or are you looking for any way to solve the desired sum?

Comment: groupby df2 sum , then merge

Comment: Hey I would like to use the intermediary dictionary or step in computing that some way to increase the speed of solving the desired sum.

Comment: I'm creating the dictionary for some other tasks along the road. Hoping to use the steps in producing the dictionary to increase the speed for solving the sum as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good way to go about it is to apply a `groupby` and `sum` on `data2`, and then map the resulting Series to `data1`:

```
data1['matches'] = data1.C2.map(data2.groupby('C3')['C4'].sum()).fillna(0)
>>> data1
      C1      C2  matches
0  Peter    kiwi      0.0
1   John  banana      7.0
2  Susan   peach      0.0
3    Joe   apple      8.0
```